# How to fix JAVA_HOME not set on Ubuntu when hadoop-env.sh is already set?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, java-home

I already set the hadoop-env.sh to :

```
# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

but still have the same error when I start the hadoop :

```
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode dyah-VirtualBox.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-dyah-VirtualBox.out
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-dyah-VirtualBox.out
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-dyah-VirtualBox.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-dyah-VirtualBox.out
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

When I type `echo $JAVA_HOME`, it shows : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`.
When I type `java -version`, it shows the version of java.

I already export java's path to the `/.bashrc`

I don't know what's going on here because I already set the things correctly according to the tutorial.

Comment: I tried to edit your formatting: There I saw to you write `# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`. It may just a typo but it could also mean that your change in `hadoop-env.sh` is ignored because `#` comments out your change. Just in case, have to tried it without the leading `#`?

Comment: oh i'm sorry. i forgot to delete the "#". it's working already. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The export statement is commented out by a leading `#`, so it has no effect.

Answer (score -2):

Is the environment variable being set globally i.e. it should be able to the user that's launching hadoop. Try (as root) manually exporting JAVA_HOME and then launching hadoop.